# Подключение к локальной базе данных

Tags: c#, база-данных

Щас читаю книгу по C# и дошел до раздела по работе с БД до этого с БД работал только на php.
Проблема в том что я не совсем пойму какой нужно выбирать драйвер (в книги автор использует Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0), у меня этого драйвера не было, нашел его на сайте ms но как я понял он не для win 7, не совсем пойму про драйвера, подскажите пожалуйста как нужно выбрать подходящий драйвер?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще то подключаться к данным можно разными способами. Например можно почитать здесь [Практическое руководство. Подключение к данным в базе данных](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fxk9yw1t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
. А вообще базы данных - это ADO.NET - найдите хорошую книгу и почитайте. Из вашего вопроса не очень понятно что именно вы сейчас изучаете.

Comment: простейшие основы ADO.NET

Comment: читай ссылку, там все довольно просто